# How does scala match on Arrays?

Tags: scala

looking through the Scala code, the convenient array creation syntax is achieved by adding an `apply` method to `object Array`.  At first, I thought this was achieved somehow through case classes because you can run the following, but this does not seem to be the case:

```
Array(1,2,3) match { case Array(a, b, c) => a + b + c }
```

I know that I also need to look at `WrappedArray` and all the superclasses, but I can't figure out how scala achieves this matching on Arrays (and I need to become more familiar with the scala collections class hierarchy).  It certainly doesn't work with a run-of-the-mill class.

```
scala>  class A(val x: Int)
scala>  new A(4) match { case A(x) => x }
<console>:9: error: not found: value A
              new A(4) match { case A(x) => x }
                                    ^
<console>:9: error: not found: value x
              new A(4) match { case A(x) => x }
```

How do they get this to work with Array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pattern match with this syntax on any class so long as you have an object with with an `unapply` or `unapplySeq` (in the case of varargs) method that returns an `Option` or `Boolean`. These are known as *extractors*. The lines in question from object `Array` are

```
  def unapplySeq[T](x: Array[T]): Option[IndexedSeq[T]] =
    if (x == null) None else Some(x.toIndexedSeq)
```

In your example you can get it to match using

```
class A(val x: Int)

object A {
  def unapply(a: A) = Some(a.x)
}
```

so now

```
scala> new A(4) match { case A(x) => x }
res1: Int = 4
```

The Programming In Scala [chapter on extractors](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html) may be useful.

For case classes, an `unapply` method is just one of the methods that is included for free, along with `toString`, `equals`, etc.

Note that the extractor doesn't have to have the same name as the class in question, and it doesn't have to be defined within an `object` object. For example, in your case you could equally write

```
val xyz = new { def unapply(a: A) = Some(a.x) } //extending java.lang.Object

new A(4) match { case xyz(x) => x }             //Int = 4
```

Comment: Just for precision : it is not possible to add to JVM array classes, but unapply/unapplySeq are typically defined in object, not classes. Scala may and does add an [Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$) object.